# Game character won't double jump c#

Tags: c#, 2d, platform

I'm trying to create a 2D platform game in unity, when I try and make the character double jump, it won't work. I was wondering if i could get any help.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    public float maxSpeed = 3;
    public float speed = 50f;
    public float jumpPower = 150f;

    public bool grounded;
    public bool canDoubleJump;

    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    private Animator anim;

    void Start ()
    {
        rb2d = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }


    void Update ()
    {

        anim.SetBool("Grounded", grounded);
        anim.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(rb2d.velocity.x));

        if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < -0.1f)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
        }

        if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0.1f)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        }

        if(Input.GetButton("Jump"))
        {
            if(grounded)
            {
                rb2d.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpPower);
                canDoubleJump = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (canDoubleJump)
                {
                    canDoubleJump = false;
                    rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(rb2d.velocity.x, 0);
                    rb2d.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpPower);

                }
            }
        }

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 easeVelocity = rb2d.velocity;
        easeVelocity.y = rb2d.velocity.y;
        easeVelocity.z = 0.0f;
        easeVelocity.x *= 0.75f;

        float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        //fake friction / easing x speed
        if(grounded)
        {
            rb2d.velocity = easeVelocity;
        }


        //moving player
        rb2d.AddForce((Vector2.right * speed) * h);

        //limiting speed
        if(rb2d.velocity.x > maxSpeed)
        {
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(maxSpeed, rb2d.velocity.y);
        }

        if(rb2d.velocity.x < -maxSpeed)
        {
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(-maxSpeed, rb2d.velocity.y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you double the `jumpPower` for a double jump?

Comment: Not exactly, no.  "Double Jump" does not mean "jump twice as high" it means "jump again while airborn."  A double jump (traditionally) can even be performed after falling off of a platform.  That said, vertical velocity should be zeroed before the jump velocity is added.

Comment: Could it be the 2D box collider, interfering with the script? @Draco18s

Comment: Not sure, you haven't exactly indicated what "doesn't work" is referring to.  Do you mean you hit "Jump" a second time and nothing happens?

Comment: @Draco18s yeah, that's exactly the problem

Comment: Oh, I bet I know what the problem is.  You can confirm it for me by commenting out `rb2d.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpPower);` inside the if(doubleJump) block.  Bet you your character doesn't jump as high when you press jump the first time.

Comment: @Draco18s Yes your right, why's that?

Comment: Writing up an answer post for you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're checking if the Jump button *is currently in the down state.*  Pressing and releasing the button often takes place over multiple frames (i.e. `Update()` is called many times in the duration of button press).

There are two ways you can fix this problem.

The easiest (and probably best) is to make this alteration:

```
if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
```

`GetButtonDown` only returns true for the frame in which the button was first pressed, and false until it is released and pressed again.

The other is to include a second variable that prevents the activation of the second block until after the button is released.  This is less ideal, but shows what's going on behind the scenes of `GetButtonDown`.

```
var isButtonDown = false;

Update() {
        if(Input.GetButton("Jump"))
        {
            if(grounded)
            {
                rb2d.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpPower);
                canDoubleJump = true;
                isButtonDown = true;
            }
            else if(!isButtonDown)
            {
                if (canDoubleJump)
                {
                    canDoubleJump = false;
                    rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(rb2d.velocity.x, 0);
                    rb2d.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpPower);

                }
            }
        }
        else {
            isButtonDown = false;
        }
    }
```

Note that this does not address the "fall off a platform and jump once" that the double-jump ability typically includes.  I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Wow, ok thank you. Your help was very much appreciated! :)

Comment: You're welcome.  By the way, include the `Unity` tag next time.  After all, you are using Unity and Unity is a tag that is recognized here.  Also don't forget to mark this as an accepted answer!  The checkmark at the top-left. ;)

Comment: @Draco18s Not the Unity tag please, the Unity3d tag. Unity is for the IoC framework, not the game engine.

Comment: Ooooh, thanks @RonBeyer! I had no idea, I've used `Unity` before not knowing that!